# How to handle a downvoted answer that is referenced by another answer?

Tags: discussion

The question is, should I delete the answer, or not.

The answer itself tackles a part of the question and is in my view valid and in the view of the one who referenced my answer worth to link.

Comment: Perhaps linking us to the example you have in mind might help? With context, it may be easier to understand what you are unsure of.

Comment: this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55949634/1447675

Comment: To be honest, that question seems awful broad; not sure there is any answer that can fully address what the asker wants.  Seems like a good candidate for closure.

Comment: I'm certainly no JavaScript expert, I'm afraid I couldn't tell you whether the answer is good or not. I'll leave this to someone who knows more than me.

Comment: Also no JavaScript expert, but there are 3 questions there. The title asks "can I reach infinity in runtime," and the body asks "what will happen if I grow a variable past the number range," and  "what are *all* the scenarios where I reach infinity in runtime" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking some guesses, since you didn't link to a specific Q/A (which is understandable).

As I understand your question, you're saying you posted an answer that (you believe) answers part of the question. Another answer to the same question references your answer, and either:

1. builds upon it, or
2. directly addresses parts of your answer and offers more information

I'd say if your answer has a net-0 or net-positive score, keep it. It's clearly helpful to someone. One or two downvotes aren't always indicative of a bad answer. If the other answer points out shortcomings in your answer, you can always edit to correct your errors.

If the answer has a net-negative score, I'd first try to see if the answer can be edited into a better shape. Self-deleting answers doesn't seem like something that should be necessary in most cases.

Comment: *"Self-deleting answers doesn't seem like something that should be necessary in most cases."* - necessity is maybe not the right word, it can be a good idea if the answer is not well-liked and can't be improved. Seems like other answers go the full monty already.